# Boom - Discrepancy in error thrown and error as response

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch, hapi.js

**This is about [boom](https://github.com/hapijs/boom) which is a plugin to Hapijs**

This is the function meant to throw an error

```
const errorThrower = (msg = 'Internal Server Error', errorCode = 500) => {
  const error = new Error(msg);
  error.httpStatusCode = errorCode;
  throw error;
};
```

And this is how I am using it in another file

```
try {
      ...
      errorThrower('Invalid client id for partner', 404);
      ...
  } catch (error) {
    return boom.boomify(error,
      {
        statusCode: error.statusCode,
      });
  }
```

Now, this results in a `500 Internal Server Error` whereas I would expect `404 Invalid client id for partner` from Boom. The log indicates the error on the console which clearly means that it wasn't caught.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Whats behind the `...` ? Some callbacks? Async code?

Comment: Just some code that shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this was quick.

So, there is no built-in property like `error.statusCode` but rather `error.httpStatusCode` which I am setting inside my `errorThrower` function.

This is why maybe `boom` is assuming a 500 as I am not providing a valid `statusCode`(`error.statusCode` is undefined).

To quote from [boom](https://github.com/hapijs/boom#boomifyerr-options),

> statusCode - the HTTP status code. Defaults to 500 if no status code is already set and err is not a Boom object.

This was the only change necessary for the correct error response:

```
return boom.boomify(error,
  {
    statusCode: error.statusCode,
  });
```

*Could have created a Boom object as well...*